# C# Attributes and attribute location/targets

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm reading up about attributes and understand that they can be made to apply to different target entities with you code - (see [Attribute Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0(VS.80).aspx)).

So, looking at the **AssemblyInfo.cs** file in my project, I can see the following:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("AttributesDemo")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
```

Which makes sense to me. An attribute whose target is the assembly.

In my code I can add an attribute on a class as follows:

```
[MyAttribute]
class MySerialzableClass
{
```

With `MyAttribute` being:

```
[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}
```

So, I got to thinking about the `assembly:` statement in the first code block. And tried this, just for experimentation:

```
[class: MyAttribute]
class MySerialzableClass
{
```

This gives the compiler warning:

> 'class' is not a recognized attribute
>   location. All attributes in this block
>   will be ignored.

So my question is this - Why do have to specify the Attribute Target on some attributes and are not requried, or permitted to for others? Moreover, for which ones must you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to specify target explicitly in case where the target is not represented in code. I know only three that targets, assembly, module and return:

```
[return: MyAttribute]
public static int meth(
```

for class specifying class: is excessive, compiler can understand what do you meant

Comment: +1 and accepted answer, although shouldn't it be 'ReturnValue:', not 'Return:'

Answer (score 5):

You can specify [attribute targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0.aspx) for any attribute usage, but only the ones that don't have a default (`assembly` and `module`) are mandatory. Also, you *must* use these annotations when you want to apply an attribute to a non-default target.

Examples of non-default targets:

```
[return: MyAttribute]   
public int Method() { ... }

public int Property {
  get;
  [param: MyAttribute] // applies to the parameter to the setter
  set;
}
```

In your example, the right target (which is the default) is `type`:

```
[type: MyAttribute] 
class MySerialzableClass { }
```

Comment: This is the best answer since it gives the correct target keyword `type:`. The global targets possible are `assembly` and `module`, and the non-global ones are `field`, `event`, `method`, `param`, `property`, `return`, and `type`.

Comment: Why one can not use `get` or `set` target? Sorry, one can use `method` target, but it is not comfortable ((

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the attribute comes right before what it affects, such as the class or method.  For assembly-wide attributes, there's no "before", so you have to specify.